# Is there a Meteorite Pickaxe

Tags: terraria

Is there any way to obtain a meteorite pickaxe? It doesn't say anything about it on the Wiki.

I have plenty of wood and 26 meteorite.

Answer (score 6):

There is no such thing as a meteorite pickaxe, what you might be thinking of is the molten pickaxe, which is made from: 20 Hellstone bars at an iron anvil, or lead anvil.

Comment: No problem, if my answer was deemed helpful you can press the check to notify others this question was already answered.

Answer (score 6):

There is no "Meteorite Pickaxe".

The only tool that can be made from Meteorite is the *Hamaxe* which is both hammer and axe.

If you can already mine meteor, then you would have a bone or tungsten pickaxe or higher. The next pickaxes would be the Gold or Platinum pickaxe.